Visual Studio 2022 Publish Fails - Unable to delete files
I am trying to Publish a sample DotNetCore project (from the basic VueJs/Core solution template) to an IIS server with the 'Delete Existing Files' option. If the app has been running, then the Publish throws errors because of files that it cannot delete. Fortunately, a second Publish succeeds as the first attempt shuts the app down and allows the files to be deleted for the second attempt.
<Target Name="AddAppOffline" BeforeTargets="Publish">
   <Message Text="Copying app_offline.htm" Importance="high" />
   <Copy SourceFiles="app_offline.htm" DestinationFolder="$(PublishDir)" />
   <Message Text="Completed Copying app_offline.htm" Importance="high" />
</Target>

<Target Name="RemoveAppOffline" AfterTargets="Publish">
   <Message Text="Deleting app_offline.htm" Importance="high" />
   <Delete Files="$(PublishDir)\app_offline.htm" />
</Target>

I am using the code above in the .csproj file that should add the app_offline.htm file into Publish folder to shut the app pool down. Despite the order shown in the VS Output window, I do not see the file being added before the Delete errors are thrown.
Build started at 1:18 AM...
1>------ Build started: Project: vuecore2024.client, Configuration: Release Any CPU ------
2>------ Build started: Project: VueCore2024.Server, Configuration: Release Any CPU ------
2>VueCore2024.Server -> 
C:\Git\Samples\2024\VueCore2024\VueCore2024.Server
\bin\Release\net8.0\VueCore2024.Server.dll
3>------ Publish started: Project: VueCore2024.Server, Configuration: Release Any CPU ------
Connecting to C:\temp\VueCore2024...
VueCore2024.Server -> C:\Git\Samples\2024\VueCore2024\VueCore2024.Server
\bin\Release\net8.0\VueCore2024.Server.dll
npm run build

> vuecore2024.client@0.0.0 build
> vite build

[36mvite v5.2.11 [32mbuilding for production...[36m[39m
transforming...
[32mΓ£ô[39m 23 modules transformed.
rendering chunks...
computing gzip size...
[2mdist/[22m[32mindex.html                 
[39m[1m[2m 0.43 kB[22m[1m[22m[2m Γöé gzip:  0.29 kB[22m
[2mdist/[22m[35massets/index-BXAxuANx.css  
[39m[1m[2m 3.73 kB[22m[1m[22m[2m Γöé gzip:  1.22 kB[22m
[2mdist/[22m[36massets/index-X070Lzgl.js   
[39m[1m[2m64.83 kB[22m[1m[22m[2m Γöé gzip: 25.70 kB[22m
[32mΓ£ô built in 547ms[39m

Copying app_offline.htm
Completed Copying app_offline.htm

VueCore2024.Server ->     C:\Git\Samples\2024\VueCore2024\VueCore2024.Server     
\obj\Release\net8.0\PubTmp\Out\
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\8.0.204\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish
\targets\PublishTargets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish.FileSystem.targets(63,5): 

Error  MSB3061: Unable to delete file     
"C:\temp\VueCore2024\Microsoft.AspNetCore.OpenApi.dll". Access to the path 
'C:\temp\VueCore2024\Microsoft.AspNetCore.OpenApi.dll' is denied.
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\8.0.204\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish
\targets\PublishTargets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish.FileSystem.targets(63,5): 

Error MSB3061: Unable to delete file 
"C:\temp\VueCore2024\Microsoft.OpenApi.dll". 
Access to the path 'C:\temp\VueCore2024\Microsoft.OpenApi.dll' is denied.
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\8.0.204\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish
\targets\PublishTargets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish.FileSystem.targets(63,5):

Error MSB3061: Unable to delete file 
"C:\temp\VueCore2024\Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.dll". Access to the path 
'C:\temp\VueCore2024\Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.dll' is denied.
 C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\8.0.204\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish
\targets\PublishTargets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish.FileSystem.targets(63,5):

Error MSB3061: Unable to delete file 
"C:\temp\VueCore2024\Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.dll". Access to the path 
'C:\temp\VueCore2024\Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.dll' is denied.
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\8.0.204\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish
\targets\PublishTargets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish.FileSystem.targets(63,5):

Error MSB3061: Unable to delete file 
"C:\temp\VueCore2024\Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.dll". Access to the path 
'C:\temp\VueCore2024\Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.dll' is denied.
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\8.0.204\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish
\targets\PublishTargets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish.FileSystem.targets(63,5): 

Error MSB3061: Unable to delete file "C:\temp\VueCore2024\VueCore2024.Server.dll". 
Access to the path 'C:\temp\VueCore2024\VueCore2024.Server.dll' is denied.

3>Build failed. Check the Output window for more details.
========== Build: 2 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Build completed at 1:18 AM and took 03.698 seconds ==========
========== Publish: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
========== Publish completed at 1:18 AM and took 03.698 seconds ==========

The path to the app_offline.htm file is working correctly as the file is there at the end of the publish if the Delete Target step is removed. My guess is that the timing is somehow off with the deletions happening before the App Pool shutdown is complete.
Any suggestion as to how to make this work on the first publish, preferably without having to resort to a external Powerscript file or something more elaborate?

Based on your scenario and description its seems Visual Studio is trying to delete files during publish that are likely locked by a running application. You can fix this by either setting the "AlwaysOverwrite" property to true in the publish profile, running Visual Studio with administrator privileges, or adding a post-deployment script that deletes leftover files after publishing.  In addition, you can introduce a delay between copying the app_offline.htm file and starting the deletion process

Yeah, it is definitely files in use that are locking the running app. Is there a specific "AlwaysOverwrite" option in the .csproj file? Do not see it in intellisense and not making a difference when I publish. I am using the "Delete Existing Files..." option in the .pubxml.
I think I tried adding a delay.  How would you do that?
